# Extjs 4 dynamically adding multiple panels to a form

Tags: dynamic, extjs4, field, panels

I have 3 panels and each panel will have 7 - 10 fields.

The main form panel contains a combo field and the 3 panels.

Based on the combo selected value i'm hiding the remaining 2 panels and showing one panel.

All these three panels have `allowBlank: false` validations for the fields.

While submitting the form, the fields which are hidden are also validated and prevents the form from submitting. So i want to disable the fields which are hidden. i'm using this code.

```
question_multiple_option.query('.component').forEach(function(c){c.setDisabled(true);});
```

But in EXT 4.X disabled fields are also validated while submitting a form.

In Ext 2.X and 3.X disabled fields are not validated and not submitted.

previously i used this code in ext 2.X

```
 Ext.getCmp('option').cascade(function(comp){
                        if (comp.isFormField) {
                            //comp.enable();
                              comp.disable();
                        }
                    });
```

Is it the right way to implement a form with multiple panels by hide and showing the panels. Or how can i add / remove a panel to a form dynamically ?.

Is there any better way to implement this kind of form.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Nicely phrased q.

It is not supposed to be validating disabled fields.

There was a [**bug**](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?154239-Validation-error-for-disabled-Checkboxgroups) about this that was fixed in 4.1. I'm not sure how it looks in whatever 4.x version you are using but you could add an override in your code to the `isValid` method of Ext.form.field.Base to match the 4.1 code if you can't migrate. Something like this:

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.field.Base, {
    isValid : function() {
        var me = this;
        return me.disabled || Ext.isEmpty(me.getErrors());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Geronimo. i have replaced the line no 370 in src/form/CheckBoxGroup.js file `isValid = Ext.isEmpty(errors)` with `isValid = me.disabled || Ext.isEmpty(errors)`. But still i'm facing the same issue. What would be the problem?

Comment: Editing that line like it says in the bug report will only effect the CheckBox field. You should add the override I mentioned above in your own code so it will apply to all form fields.

Comment: If i place the above code, disabled radiogroup buttons are also validated and remaining textfields are not validated while submitting the form